# extend sda partition under LVM

Tags: lvm

My server has 4 primary partitions with data I can't delete but I need to extend the hdd as it is running out of space.
I already increased the size of the vmdk file but when I try to create a partition I get the message `You must delete some partition and add an extended partition first` but that is the point, I can't delete a partition...

```
root@webhost [~]# lsblk
NAME                                  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                                   7:0    0  2.4G  0 loop /tmp
sda                                     8:0    0  200G  0 disk
├─sda1                                  8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                                  8:2    0 24.5G  0 part
│ ├─vg_linuxwebserver2-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0 97.5G  0 lvm  /
│ └─vg_linuxwebserver2-lv_swap (dm-1) 253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
├─sda3                                  8:3    0   25G  0 part
│ ├─vg_linuxwebserver2-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0 97.5G  0 lvm  /
│ └─vg_linuxwebserver2-lv_swap (dm-1) 253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
└─sda4                                  8:4    0   50G  0 part
  └─vg_linuxwebserver2-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0 97.5G  0 lvm  /
sr0                                    11:0    1 1024M  0 rom

root@webhost [~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000969eb

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64        3264    25701376   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda3            3264        6527    26213727+  83  Linux
/dev/sda4            6528       13054    52428127+  8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_linuxwebserver2-lv_root: 104.7 GB, 104689827840 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 12727 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_linuxwebserver2-lv_swap: 2147 MB, 2147483648 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 261 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

Can I extend for instance /dev/sda4 using gparted keeping in mind that it is part of a LVM (I am trying to avoid partitions to be deleted)?

thanks

Comment: You used all four primary partitions, but only half the disk space. You will need to delete and recreate partitions.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't want to delete any partition that is why I am asking if extending the partition using gparted would work

Comment: I know what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use gparted to extend partition n.4 and then (assuming you want to extend your logical volume using all free space) issue the following commands:

1. `pvresize`
2. `lvresize /dev/mapper/vg_linuxwebserver2-lv_root -l+100%FREE`

Anyway, I suggest you to print a sector-addressed partition table (you can switch to sector-based size using `fdisk -u`, so that if gparted fails to resize your partition, you can easily reconstruct it via `fdisk`

You can also do a binary backup of your partition table using the command

`dd if=/dev/sda of=ptable.bin bs=512 count=1`